# Read Different XML Files

Tags: java, xml

I'm making simple paint program, and in that program users are able to save their work into XML files; there are two different schemas for these XML files.

When it comes to load, I want my program to understand both schemas. That is, for the program to read a file without first knowing which of the schemas the file uses.

How should I handle this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply try to read enforcing one schema, and if it fails to validate fall back to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on the XML system you're using to read the XML files.

If your XML parser is flexible enough, check for differences in the parsed tree that would help indicate which schema was used. (for example, if their root elements were named differently, you could use that)

If your parser isn't that flexible, I'd recommend the answer suggested by ptyx, which is trying one schema out and falling back to the other if the first one fails.

Answer (score 0):

If the files have  a `DOCTYPE` at their start, this is trivial. So require that the XML files have  a `DOCTYPE`.